# Using list to navigate selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem that i can't navigate to a link on selenium using a list.

this is what i've tried

```
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='" + list_of_lists[listposition] + "'&text=Hi")
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=",list_of_lists[listposition],"&text=Hi")
```

and this is the full code

```
# list (whatsapp contacts)
a_file = open("C:/Users/Unknown/Documents/Notes/whatsapp_contacts.txt", "r")

list_of_lists = []
for line in a_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  line_list = stripped_line.split()
  list_of_lists.append(line_list)

a_file.close()

listtotal = len(list_of_lists)

print("Total:", listtotal)

listposition = 0

while listposition < listtotal:

    # navigate to website
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='" + list_of_lists[listposition] + "'&text=Hi")

    # more code
    
    listposition = listposition + 1
```

Comment: what error ar e you gettting

Comment: Where is your list ? on url or you are try to accesss in your txt file?

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the error ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str```. My list is on the text file, i add this list from text file to my list on python to be able to use in the code.

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have a list, but a list of lists, if you put an example on your post on how your list looks like will be easier for everyone